# Aligning two button images at a fixed distance in ios app-Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on an ios app where I want to have two buttons at a fixed distance from each other. Something like below:

[image]

I tried dragging one constraint between the two images. But when I run it in simulator it shows overlap as below.

[image]

Can someone guide how to put both the pictures at a fixed distance. Also, I am seeing when I turn the simulator as right in hardware option some of my buttons are not getting auto aligned to horizontal screen and doesn't get displayed. How to fix this too?

Thanks

Comment: yes...it happens because i think you pinned right and left edges of both of them

Comment: Manish your problem solved or not ?

Answer (score 2):

First of all clear all constraints. and follow below steps :

1. select both button with command button press
2. Give Width & Height constraints for both. (Pin at bottom-right side)
3. give Horizontal Centre in container constraints for both. (Align at bottom-right side)
4. Now, update all constraints (Resolve Auto-Layout Issue bottom-right side)

Hope, it's work..

Answer (score 0):

Design your view according to this image

1. Drag a new view and then put your two button in it
2. Constraint for new view

   1. Top
   2. Horizontal center
   3. Fix height and width
3. Constraint for left button

   1. Top and leading
   2. Fix height and width
4. Constraint for right button

   1. Top and traling
   2. Fix height and width

It will work defiantly.

[image]